# Parallel hashmap in haskell

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

There is an implementation of `HashMap`, in `Haskell`, but I can't find parallel version of it. It's necessary to solve problem below.

Say, I have two hashmaps `HashMap a b`, I want to union it with condition, Now I use `unionWith` function, but the problem is that equivalence of my `a` keys is very long procedure (it's a graphs). So I'd like to perform it in parallel. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `newtype` around `HashMap`, then define a new `Eq` instance that is as parallel as you like using `Control.Parallel`. Unfortunately you'll have to write all that code yourself, I don't think there is any out of the box parallel implementations.

```
import Control.Parallel

newtype ParHashMap k v = ParHashMap { unPar :: HashMap k v }

instance (Eq k, Eq v) => Eq (ParHashMap k v) where
    ParHashMap hm1 == ParHashMap hm2 = ...
```

I'm not sure which `HashMap` you're using (I recommend `unordered-containers`), so I can't write the `Eq` instance, but it should be fairly simple to evaluate the equality of each node in parallel.